# express.js route with or without a parameter

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I use node.js v8.11.1 and express 4.16.3.

Say I have the following route

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res){
```

I want to do something like

```
if(req.params.id) then query1
else //no id param in the url
query2
```

So, I could go either to `http://localhost:3000/` or to `http://localhost:3000/504` and the routes will respond accordingly.

but when I go to `http://localhost:3000/` I just get `Cannot GET /`

How do I fix my routes?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you setup two routes (one with id and one without it). If you do this, you don't need an if statement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make your route parameter optional using `?` operator.

Change your route with following:

`app.get('/:id?', function(req, res){`

Now it should work for both: http://localhost:3000/ or http://localhost:3000/504

Comment: Since a query begins with a questionmark I thought this answer was somehow misleading. Internet tells me I was wrong. But I can't find any docs on it.
(p.s. The questionmark can't be part of regex either because it's not in brackets)

Comment: This is well explained under "Route paths" section. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: no not really. it says nothing about optional parameters. only regexed parameters which use brackets for regex. this answer does not use brackets and it still works.

Comment: Actually in that documentation link express adds that they use "path-to-regexp" package and in the documentation of that package you'll find the "optional parameter"
https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#optional

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @n32303, you can do:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   //Called when there is no id specified
}
app.get('/:id', function(req, res){
   // Called when an Id is specified (req.params.id will be set )
}
```

To eliminate the need for an if statement